# Batch-File wait for ClickOnce Application to install before moving to next line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that installs a ClickOnce Application. I want it to wait for the application to be installed so then it can process the rest of the commands on the next lines.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
call nameofyourbatchthatinstallsclickonce
```

which will wait for the `call`ed batch to finish before proceeding

---

To run your existing installation as a part of a single batch:

```
rem then the things you want to do before Clickonce is installed

call :existingbatch

rem then the things you want to do after Clickonce is installed

... and so on

goto :eof

:existingbatch
rem copy your existing batch in here.
rem make sure it exits the routine either with an
rem exit statement or a goto :eof
```

Whenever a batch file reaches end-of-file or an `exit` statement, it will terminate.

If it contains a `call`ed subroutine - and the syntax here is `call :label` where the label must have the initial colon for an internal subroutine; ie. a subroutine with the current batch (without the colon, batch will attempt to find an external executable - then the subroutine terminates and execution returns to the statement following the `call` statement.

`goto :eof` is a statement that batch recognises as `go to physical end-of-file`. The colon is mandatory.

Comment: Is there no way to do this within a single batch file?

Comment: I think this will only work if the installed does not run in the background.

Comment: @marged True, but with the scant information we have, it's difficult to advise further. We'd need to know precisely what executables would be running during the installation or we'd need to search for a file/directory/registry change. OP must advise of precisely how this would be accomplished - editing-in the installation batch would be a start...

Comment: Yes, Mumbles has to provide that information. Then we can tell if using some `start /wait` trick will do or if we have to scan for a process with `tasklist` or something similar.